# How to Retrieve Specific Data in Firebase Using Table Cells?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I'm kinda new to Javascript so please don't bite. I wrote simple function that displays my Firebase users in table, I'm using Jquery to create this, so far my code looks like that:

```
 userRef.on("child_added", snap => {
             var username = snap.child("name").child("name").val();
             var surname = snap.child("name").child("surname").val();
             $("#user_table").append("<tr><td>"+ username +"</td></tr>")
             });
```

now i want to display each users data by clicking on his nickname in table, im doing it like that :

```
                 $("#user_table").on('click', 'td', function() {
               userRef.on("child_added", snap =>{
                cosValue = snap.child("cos").child("cos").val();
                alert(cosValue);
              })
             });
```

and it displays all of my users data.. not this specific one that i clicked on, how can i solve that ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 userRef.on("child_added", snap => {
         var username = snap.child("name").child("name").val();
         var surname = snap.child("name").child("surname").val();
         var cosValue = snap.child("cos").child("cos").val();
         $("#user_table").append("<tr onClick=\"displayCos(" + cosValue + ")\"><td>"+ username +"</td></tr>")
         });

 function displayCos(cos) {
   alert(cos);  //or any other action, e.g. open a PopUp window, display it in another div or table, etc.
 }
```

You don't need the second `.on("child_added",...`

Also, you may do that with an onClick listener, instead of coding that inline in the `tr` tag (see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp).

Comment: After 2 days i have one more question, i cant display values that contain colon symbol e.g. "12:30", how do deal with it?

Comment: Well to be honest i cant even retrieve data that contains letter, eg. "12h30min"

Comment: @BartSumps Please create a new question with all the details: your code, the database structure and the error you see in the console.